# Append column to view

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I get this data from my view. I need to take the information and shift the different Amount Types into columns of their own. This can be done by creating a view for each type and combining them later into a single view. But is there a a way to do this all in a single view?

I was thinking about using subquery or union, but I am relatively new to this and not sure if it's the best course of action.

Comment: What you're looking for is a [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410\(v=sql.105\).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising if I can figure out the syntax.

Comment: Thanks again to you and @E. Monk, I'm still working on it, but I think this is going the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a pivot:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [YOUR_VIEW]
) piv
PIVOT
(MAX(Amount) FOR Type IN ([401k], [Roth], [Employer Match]) thisshoudwork
```